# Can't seem to utilize Spacer() between text() and textfield()

Tags: swiftui

I can't seem to get the Spacer() function to work when I'm within an HStack and trying to create space between my Text and Textfield views. The Spacer works to space out other areas of the view, but whenever I attempt to space between these two elements, it doesn't work.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```swift
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(height: 2, alignment: .top)
            .foregroundColor(Color("grey2"))
        Text("Tickets")
            .kerning(0.5)
            .scaledFont(name: "Gotham Medium", size: 18)
            .foregroundColor(Color("grey4"))
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.bottom, 3)
            .padding(.top, 35)
        Rectangle()
            .frame(height: 2, alignment: .top)
            .foregroundColor(Color("grey2"))

        HStack {
            Text("Ticket URL")
                .kerning(0.5)
                .scaledFont(name: "Gotham Book", size: 16)
                .foregroundColor(Color("spaceblack"))

            Spacer()

            TextField("Enter URL", text: $url)
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .padding()

        Rectangle()
            .frame(height: 2, alignment: .top)
            .foregroundColor(Color("grey2"))
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(Color.red)
```

Comment: `TextField` consumes all available width similarly to Spacer, actually. So what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try adding `.fixedSize()` modifier to your `TextField`

```
   TextField("Enter URL", text: $url)
       .fixedSize()
```

or set a `frame` like so

```
   TextField("Enter URL", text: $url)
       .frame(width:200, height:50, alignment:.leading)
```

The problem is that `TextField` and `Spacer()` would take all available space and in this case `TextField` gets the priority; However, if you specify a fixed size or a frame to it then `TextField` won't stretch to take full space instead it will be fixed.

`.fixedSize` would allow your `TextField` to start small but eventually it will keep stretching the more text you write which can cause unwanted behavior.

`.frame` will fix your size to the provided width and hence there won't be any stretch and `Spacer` will have priority to take available space.

Comment: That did it, thank you. Really appreciate the explanation as well.