# SwiftUI: Spacer not pushing content to the side after layout change to right-to-left

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I changed my app's layout from left-to-right to right-to-left, by adding the `.environment(...)` as shown below:

```
struct RegisterView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    Group {
        RegisterView(showReg: .constant(true))
            .preferredColorScheme(.light)
            .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
       }
    }
 }
```

But then, the `Spacer()` isn't working as intended: it's not pushing the content of an HStack to the opposite sides as it used to. In the screenshot below, you can see that all the entries in the `form` are pushed to the opposite sides except for the one before last. If you look at the code, that entry corresponds to the second `HStack` (the one that has `text: $stock` inside). The only difference is the order of the `TextField` and `Text`: when `TextField` precedes `Text`, the `Spacer()` behaves as one space.

[image]

Comment: Works as-designed. TextField consumes all available space. If you want to restrict it to some width give it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution on this thread:

[Can't seem to utilize Spacer() between text() and textfield()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363364/cant-seem-to-utilize-spacer-between-text-and-textfield)

I just added the `.fixedSize()` modifier to `TextField`, which prevents `TextField` from taking priority.